# Extract Image Sources from text in PHP - preg_match_all required

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match-all

I have a little issue as my preg_match_all is not running properly.

what I want to do is extract the src parameter of **all the images** in the post_content from the wordpress which is a string - not a complete html document/DOM (thus cannot use a document parser function)

I am currently using the below code which is unfortunately too untidy and works for only 1 image src, where I want all image sources from that string

```
preg_match_all( '/src="([^"]*)"/', $search->post_content, $matches);

if ( isset( $matches ) )
{  

foreach ($matches as $match) 
{

if(strpos($match[0], "src")!==false)
{
$res = explode("\"", $match[0]);
echo $res[1];
}

}

}
```

can someone please help here...

Comment: we can take the $search->post_content as any string containing single or multiple image tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using regular expressions to parse an HTML document can be very error prone. Like in your case where not only `IMG` elements have an [`SRC` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) (in fact, that doesn’t even need to be an HTML attribute at all). Besides that, it also might be possible that the attribute value is not enclosed in double quote.

Better use a HTML DOM parser like [PHP’s *DOMDocument*](http://php.net/book.dom) and its methods:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($search->post_content);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    if ($img->hasAttribute('src')) {
        echo $img->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - albeit - @$doc->loadHTML($search->post_content); - worked for me instead - the $search->post_content was not a valid markup... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DOM parser with HTML strings, it is not necessary to have a complete HTML document. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks mate, I used the above method with a little modifications :)